# Can javascript catch window functions?

Tags: javascript, bots, fraud-prevention

I am writing bot fraud detection system and some softwares use javascript window function to manipulate with pages like `window.scrollTo()`.

So I am writing **javascript library to set on my websites** for detection.
The question is can I catch all events and functions on page? For example, if I catch `window.scrollTo()` or `document.getElementById('id').click()` on pages of my websites, this will mean that it's a bot (robot), because my websites don't have script to trigger that events.

Comment: I don't know about you, but whenever I make a bot to do something it's either done by having it move the mouse (eg. AutoIt) or just calling the server directly without the use of a browser...

Comment: Agree, mouse uses to clicks. But what if you emulate mobile device? This way I would try to catch mobile-bots at least.

Comment: @sirjay there are various frameworks for testing user interfaces in the browser, and those simulate user interaction as close as possible (including touch events, mouse movement, ...). So with your approach, you would only be able to detect really simple bots. To detect advanced bots you need to check if click timings, mouse movements, ... are atypically.